# How can I align equations on the left in this system?

Tags: equations

I have this code for building an equation system in Latex. I would like to align equation to the left.

```
\begin{equation}
    $$$\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
    \begin{aligned}
    (x_{i},Pa_{j(X_{i})}),\\
    j=1 \\
    r(X_{i},Pa_{j}(X_{i}|Pa{1}(X_{i}),...,Pa{j-1}(X_{i}))),\\
    j=2,...,m
    \end{aligned}
    \end{array}
    \right .$$$
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include an `&` at the start of each line within the `aligned` environment, this will align each line with the left edge.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    $$$\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
    \begin{aligned}
    &(x_{i},Pa_{j(X_{i})}),\\
    &j=1 \\
    &r(X_{i},Pa_{j}(X_{i}|Pa{1}(X_{i}),...,Pa{j-1}(X_{i}))),\\
    &j=2,...,m
    \end{aligned}
    \end{array}
    \right .$$$
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... what's happening with the equation number being lower than the actual equation? Also, why `$$$`...`$$$`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cases` for this, since it aligns the first column on the left:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Pa}{Pa}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    (x_i, \Pa_j(X_i)), \\
    j = 1 \\
    r(X_i, \Pa_j(X_i \mid \Pa_1(X_i), \dots, \Pa_{j - 1}(X_i))), \\
    j = 2, \dots, m
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

However, based on your layout, you might be interested in

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Pa}{Pa}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    r(x_i, \Pa_j(X_i)),                                          & j = 1,          \\
    r(X_i, \Pa_j(X_i \mid \Pa_1(X_i), \dots, \Pa_{j - 1}(X_i))), & j = 2, \dots, m
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

where you have conditionals for the `cases`.